# Getting Facebook Page Admin with Page Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Given a facebook page id and using a page access token, is there a way to find the id of the pages' administrators?

I have been looking into the API docs for pages (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) and have not found anything. Is there a specific permission that gives access to this? If so, how do I retrieve the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, I found that it's possible given that the page access token has the **manage_pages** permission.

This will work by calling:

```
graph.facebook.com/{page-id}?fields=roles&access_token={your-access-token-goes-here}
```

The response looks something like this:

```
{
  "roles": {      
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Robert M. Vunabandi",
        "id": "{some-id}",
        "tasks": [
          "ANALYZE",
          "ADVERTISE",
          "MODERATE",
          "CREATE_CONTENT",
          "MANAGE"
        ],
        "is_active": true
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "{some-hash-strings}",
        "after": "{some-hash-strings}"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "{page-id-same-as-in-api-call}"
}
```

If the **manage_pages** permission is not given in the access token, instead you would see:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#283) Requires manage_pages permission to manage the object",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 283,
    "fbtrace_id": "{some-facebook-trace-string}"
  }
}
```